# Why doesn't calling log.info produce output?

Tags: groovy

Please look at this piece of code:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger

class Base {

  Logger log = new Logger(Base.getClass().name);

  static main(args) {
    def b = new Base();
    b.log.info('hello');
  }

}
```

When I compile it I don't see any errors or warnings.
But when I try to execute it I see empty output.
Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't instantiate a new `Logger`, use `Logger.getLogger()` to retrieve/create the logger you want.

```
 Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Base.class.name)
 LOGGER.info('hello')
```

However, if you want to use `new Logger()`, it looks like you just need to assign a handler to show you the log output.

```
Logger LOGGER = new Logger(Base.class.name)
LOGGER.addHandler(new java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler())
LOGGER.info('hello')
```

Comment: Thx. Did not know that.